# How to set a custom DNS for an android app using webview?

Tags: android, webview, dns, nameservers

I want to use Cloudflare DNS servers which is 1.1.1.1 when webview is fetching url. I tried this in onCreate but did not work:

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "8.8.8.8"); 
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,google");
```

**Please help.**